# How to make new dataframe from raw dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, python-re

This is raw DF.

```
sentence = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': ['<Donald Trump:PS> is <America:LC> President. He came to <Japan:OG> in <July 20:DT>', '<NC Soft:OG>is established in  <Match, 1993:DT>', '<NC Soft:OG>is one of the best game company.']})
```

THis is the result that I want to make.

```
       PS        LC       DT               OG
0 Donald Trump  America   20-Jul    
1               Japan     Match, 1993   NC Soft
```

Comment: You should provide reproducible versions of you data (**text**, not images)

Comment: Note: the first paragraph is not a dataframe. You need to create a parser, and the parses may put data in a database (or maybe direct in a dataframe, but I recommend to do in two steps). Just program it. I do not think there is a ready available solution (but on the first item, there may be a parser already available)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extractall` and `pivot`:

```
(df['sentence']
 .str.extractall(r'<([^<>:]+):(\w+)>')
 .droplevel('match')
 .pivot(columns=1, values=0)
 .rename_axis(columns=None)
 )
```

Output:

```
            DT       LC       OG            PS
0      July 20  America    Japan  Donald Trump
1  Match, 1993      NaN  NC Soft           NaN
2          NaN      NaN  NC Soft           NaN
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': ['<Donald Trump:PS> is <America:LC> President. He came to <Japan:OG> in <July 20:DT>', '<NC Soft:OG>is established in  <Match, 1993:DT>']})
```

Comment: The problem is 'Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape' 
Raw DF doesn't have duplicate. May be result DF has duplicate

Comment: Then update your example. Do you have several of the same DT/OG/... per row?

Comment: Yes I added <NC Soft:OG>is one of the best game company In raw sentence DF

Comment: Still works fine. There is no duplicate in your updated example